# How to define Global variable outside class?

Tags: java

I'd like to define variable which can share values to classes.

so I tried as following.

But It occured error.

How to share a value to classes?

```
package com.company;

    /////// Error occurred ///////
    int sharedValue = 100;   // <- How to share to classes?
    //////////////////////////////

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            sharedValue += 10;

            GlobalTest globalTest = new GlobalTest();
            globalTest.printGlobalValue();
        }
    }

    class GlobalTest {
        void printGlobalValue() {
            System.out.println(sharedValue);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare it as a static value in your class:

```
public class Main {
    public static int sharedValue = 100;
    ....
}
```

and access it from other classes using:

```
Main.sharedValue
```

Answer (score 1):

use static in a class instead

```
public class Blah {
    public static int a = 100;
}
```

can be accessed by Blah.a

Answer (score 0):

You can also add public getter method to access sharedValue as below:

```
public class Main {

   private int sharedValue;
    public void setSharedVallue(int sv)
    {
        sharedValue=sv;
    }
    public int getSharedvalue()
    {
        return sharedValue;
    }
    // Other code.
}
```